# error when try debug c++ ndk

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk

when i try to debug c++ ndk in my android phone with android studio 1.5.this error occured:

Error while launching debug server on device: com.android.tools.ndk.run.DebuggerContext$StartServerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: run-as is broken (please see http://b.android.com/187955 for details)

i read http://b.android.com/187955 but cant fixed this.
even i root my android phone to debugger root access but not fixed this issue.
any can help me?

thanks.

Comment: Did you run those commands listed there and did they result in the expected output and no error messages?